# BackgroundJob.Enqueue vs new BackgroundJobClient()

Tags: c#, hangfire

Using Hangfire, I want to dynamically enqueue the jobs to different queues, using some criteria.

So far we are not using queues and do something like this

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<SimpleUploadWorkflow>(j=> j.DoJob())
```

In the documentation I've seen that I can use the following code to set the queue programmatically

```
var client = new BackgroundJobClient();
var state = new EnqueuedState("critical"); // Use the "critical" queue

client.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!"), state);
```

My question is should I use the client like this?
If I understand correctly method BackgroundJob.Enqueue creates the client as a singleton, so it feels wrong to create a new `BackgroundJobClient` everytime.

What is the recommended way to implement something like this?
I know I can use the [Queue] attribute, but I want my queues to be taken from the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create `BackgroundJobClient` instance everytime, you can DI it using `IBackgroundJobClient` either through ctor:

```
private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient;
public Service(IBackgroundJobClient client)
{
  _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
}
```

Or if you want scoped lifetime, you can inject `IServiceScopeFactory` in ctor and then in your method you can resolve `IBackgroundJobClient` in a following way:

```
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var backgroundJobClient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundJobClient>();
```

And regarding queue name, you could inject `IOptions` or `IOptionsMonitor` to retrieve it from your appsettings/secrets. Here's link to [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ioptionsmonitor)

Comment: Do you know if it's ok to create a Client everytime though? Like is it an expensive operation?

Comment: Regarding operation cost hard to say, but I see not reason not to use DI. That can be extremely beneficial during unit testing.

In hangfire official samples they either do ctor injection - [reference](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/856ed3f5938e44c14167b2653c1a1d3e778c1f65/samples/NetCoreSample/Program.cs#L123). Alternative way is to use factory pattern - they create a background job factory which resolves client - [reference](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/5b696d4174e13c3dd9489cc6a863d3417c632e31/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/Dashboard/AspNetCoreDashboardContext.cs#L51)